# Преобразование JSON в Embed

Tags: python, discord.py, disnake

Имеется данный JSON файл имеющий название `emb.json`:

```
{
  "content": null,
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "s",
      "color": null
    }
  ],
  "attachments": []
}
```

Этот файл нужно прочитать и преобразовать в **embed** сообщение в дискорде(c выводом по команде конечно же). Желаемый результат выглядит следующим образом: [image: embed]

Я пытался гуглить, сам сидеть и сталкивался только с ошибками, мой код выглядит так(я использую disnake):

```
@commands.command(name = 'rules')
    async def rules(self, ctx):
        with open('emb.json') as json_file:
            emb = json.load(json_file)

        embed = disnake.Embed(emb)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: а с какими ошибками вы имели дело?

Comment: @Acinit , Много ошибок, ближе всего я был к успеху когда вероятно столкнулся с ошибкой `CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embeds.0: List item values of ModelType are required`, я предполагаю что это из за того что json неправильно записан так как я делал его через дискхук, но всё же было бы хорошо увидеть реализацию json в embed на случай если я не прав.

Comment: ну вот гляну в тырнетах и документациях, вижу что `embed` сообщения создаются через объект `discord.Embed`, а далее выставляются параметры (`title` и `description`) и поля через дополнительные команды, такие как `set_author` и `add_field`

Comment: Что как бы говорит о модельности данной процедуры, не позволяющей явно присвоить `json` объект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема связана с самим json файлом, лучше всего делать `embed` записав его в коде и с помощью `Discord.Embed.to_dict(embed)` преобразовать в словарь и затем в json, пример рабочего `embed` в json выглядит так:

```
{
    "type": "rich",
    "description": "Описание",
    "title": "Заголовок"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой, просто нужно убрать вот эти строчки:

```
  "content": " ",
  "embeds": [
```

и соответствующие им скобки

ну и сам json я помещал в эмбед вот так:

````
with open('embed.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
@bot.command()
async def json(ctx):
    
    embed = disnake.Embed.from_dict(data)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````